# mouse over adapted for tochscreen phone

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a card that flips (business card like) using css I [found](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1358).  I made the card and it works on Chrome, IE10 and Firefox. I am attempting to try to make it work on touchscreen phones.  I have read that using `:focus` along side the `:hover` works for smartphones.  I insterted this code into the css and this allows the user to flip the card but not to flip it back.  I was hoping to get the functionality where a swipe or touch of the card could flip/re-flip the card as many times as desired.

As the code takes up a bit more space here is the JSFiddle link to the flip card: http://jsfiddle.net/trinker/ZG9jA/3/